# Gradle Custom Task With Input

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have to create a gradle custom task in KOTLIN with different args as input.
So based on the args, the custom task should run other tasks.

e.g: I want to run:

```
./gradlew ci type=release distribution=true version=1.2.2
```

OR

```
./gradlew ci type=debug distribution=true version=1.2.2
```

This command should run tasks:  ***clean***, ***assembleRelease*** OR ***assembleDebug*** (based on type param) and also another task to distribute the artifact (already have this one) if the *distribute* param is true.

Question 1: Is there any way to create a custom task that runs other tasks based on external params?

Question 2: Is there any way to inject the args? (the above commands are not valid I think)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass properties with `-P` command and here is an example.

```
task passP() {
    if (customProp.equals("myProp")) {
        println customProp
    }
}
```

this will only print if you execute the following command `Gradle -PcustomProp=myProp passP`

Now that you can pass parameters, You can clean, assembleRelease OR assembleDebug according to the passed parameters.

There Are two ways you can achieve that.

First way :

Make a gradle custome task to execute another gradle command which do not look neat. but the code will look like this

```
task passP(type: Exec) {
    commandLine("cmd", "/c")
    if (customProp.equals("clean")) {
        args "gradle clean"
    }
}
```

This will execute a normal clean if you passed `clean` as a parameter.

The second way :

You would be using `finializeBy` keyword

You can call the 3 tasks according to the passed parameters.

The code will be something like this (not tested) :

```
task passP() {
    if (customProp.equals("clean")) {
        tasks.named("clean") { finalizedBy("passP") }
    if (customProp.equals("debug")) {
        tasks.named("assembleDebug ") { finalizedBy("passP") }
    }
}
```

The first way work 100%, But am not sure about the second one, As am only used to use `finalizedBy` out side of the custom task scope.